# Using Fsolve to solve N-1 equations in N-1 unknowns

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

I've been looking around but I can't seem to figure out how I should use fsolve to solve my system of nonlinear equations.

so I have a function `k`, and I know that I want `.01` as the starting value (required input for fsolve I believe). I also know that `k(1000) =12`
Lastly, I have a formula for `k`,

```
    k(N) = (1/(k(N).^.5 + .9*k(N) -k(N+1))) - ((.94 * .5 *k(N+1)^(1-.5) + .9)/(k(N+1)^.5 + 
   .9*k(N+1) - k(N+2)))
```

with `N 1:1000`. I figured I could just say fsolve(k(N), .01), but with the formula in place of `k(N)` (or is defining `k(N)` in a separate function necessary?), but I exceed the dimensions of `N` and also have issues with dimensions matching since there is `N, N+1, and N+2` in the equation.

I think my issue may be stemming from the fact that I have defined vector valued functions where in reality I want them to be single valued, from `1:1000`,but I don't know how to represent this in matlab (obviously I can't type in 1000 equations).

Any ideas, suggestions, or comments?

Comment: But what value are you trying to solve for? `N` is an input and there are no other unknowns in your equation. You know `k(0)` is `0.01` and from there you can calculate `k(1)` by just rearranging your equation and then keep substituting values in iteratively to find `k(N)`...

Comment: Oh I see there is a `k(N+2)` term, I think that implies that you'll need to adjacent starting values... i.e. you must know `k(0)` and `k(1)` or `k(1000)` and `k(1001)`...

Comment: I have been told that fsolve is what I can use to solve the system when I know k(0) and k(1000), but I do not know how. It is also possible, although not too likely, that I was told wrong.

Comment: I suppose if you parameter that adjust is `k(1)` and your target is to make `k(1000)` be `12` then you could solve it with `fsolve`...

Comment: It is true that the target is to make k(1000) be 12.

Comment: That sounds correct, I suggest you create a toy example of this problem where the target is something like `k(5)` = whatever and also simplify the formula for `k(N)` as well and try solve that.

Comment: Are you sure you have N-1 equations in N-1 unknowns? Your unknowns would be k(1)-->k(N-1) but you'll have equations only from s=1 to s=N-2 if k(N+1) is not definite

Comment: Or is your question : Given an initial value k(1) and the value k(N), what's the vector [k(2),...,k(N-1)] that verifies the constraints? (in that case i got some working code)

Comment: Moreover : Can you rewrite the equation you have for k? It's pretty unclear at the moment (Notably the ,.01 part at the end)

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what you said: given an initial value for k(1), and an ending value k(N), how can I find the vector [k(2,...,k(N-1)] that verify the constraints. However, the k(2),...k(N-1) needs to be of the form specified for k(N) above. and I will clean up the equation. My apologies.

Comment: Okay, i'll post some working code on monday